# Apache Pig Group by and Filter if multiple values exist?

Tags: apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

I am trying to group multiple rows with the same IDs, and then check for each tuple in the group if it contains both values, for example:

```
(10461 , 55 )
(10435 , 17 )
(10435 , 11 )
(10435 , 72 )
(10437 , 11 )
(10830 , 72 )
```

After I group it via: `groupedData = group dataPoints by data_id;`

I get :

```
(10461 ,{(10461 , 55)})


(10435 ,{(10435 , 17),(10435 , 11),(10435 , 72)})
```

I want to filter and get the value of `10435` if it contains `17` and `11`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `FOREACH` to filter the bags, and then check for empty bags. Note I'm not sure what you've called fields with the numbers (55, 17, 11 etc.) so this is `value` in the code below - replace as needed!

```
filteredBags = FOREACH groupedData {
    seventeen = FILTER dataPoints BY value == 17;
    eleven = FILTER dataPoints BY value == 11;
    GENERATE
    group AS data_id,
    seventeen,
    eleven;
}

nonNullBags = FILTER filteredBags BY NOT IsEmpty(seventeen) AND NOT IsEmpty(eleven);

finalIds = FOREACH nonNullBags GENERATE data_id;
```